# i do have a lot of family here

Tags: verb-forms

I am writing to a girl who lives close to California, I asked her whether she has a big family there and she responded:

> Yes I do have a lot of family here with me. Uncles and aunts yes and some live in Chicago.

Is "**I do have**" correct English? I mean, isn't correct to say "**I have**" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both variants are correct. The first variant is called [emphatic "do"](http://grammar.about.com/od/e/g/Emphatic-do.htm). In this case "do" will be stressed in oral speech. In your case this emphasis is probably intended to affirm your guess that the girl had a big family here.